# Аналоги babel для разбора JSX в браузере

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, babel, jsx

Нашел в интернете неплохой [набор компонентов](http://elemental-ui.com/) для React. Манипулируя ими можно многократно ускорить процесс разработки веб-сайта, относительно написания css селекторов в индивидуальном порядке или использованием тех же готовых [наборов селекторов](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Но есть несколько проблем, а именно: Babel.js(транслятор JSX, рекомендуемый разработчиками React) требует предварительно переводить JSX в обычный JavaScript

```
«Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts server-side. See setup build systems for more information.»
```

Как следствие для меня он становится неприменимым: я хочу написать составные части страницы используя эти компоненты прямо как html теги, склеить вместе и вывести браузеру для дальнейшего отображения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникают несколько вопросов. Есть ли альтернативный инструмент для трансляции JSX в обычных JavaScript прямо на веб странице? Почему то, что я хочу сделать, плохо? Есть ли какие-либо ещё наборы инструментов, позволяющие сделать верстку быстрее и проще?

Comment: Что значит Babel требует? Babel переводит. Приведенная надпись просто предупреждает, что компиляция в браузере имеет ограничения и рпедлагает скомпилировать для использования в продуктивной среде. Из вопроса не ясно. Вы используете webpack, gulp или подобные скрипты? Или вы подключаете реакт как скрипт с cdn?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Реакт подключаю как скрипт с cdn. Вопрос скорее о том, где можно поискать подобные тулкиты виджетов для веба

Comment: транспилеров js кроме babel скорей всего и не найдете. Лучше настроить вебпак, писать jsx как вам нравится, только к сайту подключать уже компилированный js